# I built my own button component and I can't get it to work

Tags: react-native, react-native-button

I built my own button component using React Native and I am trying to use it in my code. All I am trying to do for now is to get it to log a console message and for some reason it's not doing it.

Button Component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

class Button extends Component {
  render(){
    const { onPress, children } = this.props;
    const { buttonStyle, textStyle } = styles;

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={ onPress } style={ buttonStyle }>
        <Text style={ textStyle }>
          { children }
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Code using the Button

```
class FlashcardMenuDetail extends Component {
  onButtonPress() {
    console.log('You pushed the button');
  }

  render() {
    const { title } = this.props.flashcard;

    return (
      <Card>
        <CardItem>
          <Button onpress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
            { title }
          </Button>
        </CardItem>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}
```

I can push the button but nothing shows up on the console window.

Comment: The `onpress` props is all lowercase on your Button component call. And you deconstruct it like so: `const { onPress, children } = this.props;`

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I feel like a dope right now.

Comment: No problem, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is no arrow function in the button you made `onPress` When the function of the function is used, only the console log is left because the return value is imported. You have to add an arrow function.

```js
export const makeButton = (props) => {
    const { title = "title", buttonStyle = {}, textStyle = {}, onPress } = props;

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress} style={buttonStyle}>
            <Text style={textStyle}>{props.title}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};
```

**Usage**

```js
import { makeButton } from 'path/makeButton.js';


      <Card>
        <CardItem>
         <makeButton
            title="get console.log"
            onPress={() => onButtonPress() }
            buttonStyle ={{ /* some styles for button */ }}
            textStyle={{ /* styles for button title */ }}
        />
        </CardItem>
      </Card>
```